# Can you create a new Model instance without saving it to the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a whole bunch of instances of a model object in Laravel, then pick the optimal instance and save it to the database.  I know that I can create an instance with `Model::create([])`, but that saves to the database.  If possible I'd like to create a bunch of models, then only "create" the one that is best.

Is this possible?

I am using Laravel 5.0

Comment: How do you choose your best model? You could created a condition that will save to whatever model you want to save though.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You create a new model simply by instantiating it:

```php
$model = new Model;
```

You can then save it to the database at a later stage:

```php
$model->save();
```

Comment: That is a little too easy.   I don't know how i overlooked that option.

Comment: When instantiating like this, you can load the model with initial property values just like with `create()`: `$model = new Model(['name' => 'foo', ...]);`

Answer (score 37):

You can create instances with `Model::make()`.  It works the same way as `create` but it doesn't save it.

Whether or not this is best practice is another matter entirely.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's good practice myself, but I think this could come in handy if you had to instantiate models off the payload from another service, and your current application is not supposed to preserve the data.

Comment: Perfect for consuming third party services

Comment: @gyohza there's nothing bad practice about this. It's documented in the API.

Comment: Model::make() is a wrapper for Model::newModelInstance(), which is a wrapper for Model::newInstance(). You can safely use any of those to create the model in memory, without it persisting. Useful if you need to make further manipulations in memory, before saving the model to the db.

Comment: Php stan will report 
> Called 'Model::make()' which performs unnecessary work, use 'new Model()'.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it is possible different ways: you can use the **mass assignment** without saving.

Please remember to set first the `$fillable` property in your model.

**WAY #1**: using the method **fill**

```php
$model = new YourModel;

$model->fill([
    'field' => 'value',
    'another_field' => 'another_value'
]);

$model->save();
```

**WAY #2**: using the constructor

```php
$model = new YourModel([
    'field' => 'value',
    'another_field' => 'another_value'
]);

$model->save();
```

---

In `YourModel` set the `$fillable` property with the fileds allowed for mass assignment:

```php
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['field', 'another_field'];
    // ...
}
```

---

Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Without fillable you can write `$model->field = 'value'` to make it work, but it results in a bit more verbose code because you will have to set each property line by line.

Answer (score 2):

there is also a [method](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_newModelInstance) you can call it statically to get new instance:

```
 $modelInstance =   $modelName::newModelInstance();
```

it takes `array $attributes = []` as a parameter

Comment: Yep nice - and this is essentially a wrapper for Model::newInstance()

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, on laravel 10.

Car::factory()->make() : will create an object without saving it to database
Car::factory()->create() : will create an object and save it to database

Comment: Model::factory() method is used get the set of defined default attributes used for testing Models. So, the answer seems not to be applicable.